# Django Could not import settings 'myfolder.settings'

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.4 and have the lay-out as recommended.

```
mysite/
     manage.py

     mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
     myapp/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        admin.py
        views.py
```

This is the error i get when i run syncdb

```
raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module  named mysite.settings
```

I'll have set 
`os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")`
in wsgy and in manage files

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with PyTools

Comment: No module named myfolder.settings.

Comment: sorry, i have correct the question. no module named mysite.settings

Comment: can you do `python manager.py syncdb` from the command line ?

Comment: if i activate my virtualenv with cmd prompt manually and not with visual studio i can run the command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that to work you need to define your PYTHONPATH first.

Here's something to read: http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm, but I'm sure you can google it!

1. For Windows 7, you need to go to your Computer icon, right-click, choose Properties;
2. Pick "Advanced system settings";
3. In the "Advanced" Tab, click the "Environment Variables";
4. Create a new "System variable";
5. Name it PYTHONPATH ... put a value like "c:\projects;c\projects\mysite";
6. You can test it by opening a command prompt window and type in "echo %PYTHONPATH%";

If you're not familiar with what I've described above, you need to read more.